# After running a view controller custom transition back and forward the view controller stops responding (but the app doesn't crash entirely)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have two view controllers and from the first one I show the second one by a modal segue, which presentation style is set to `over current context`. I also use blur effect which appears during the transition and disappears after it.
I've created a demo app to show how the transition looks like:

[image]

Here, the second view controller contains a `UIScrollView`, and on top of that, a yellow rectangle, which is another `UIView` with a `UIButton` on it. That `UIButton` also closes the view controller. Also, as you can see, I've set the background color to `clear`, so the blur effect is visible.

Now, in my project the transition is basically the same, except, my view controllers are "heavier". 
The first view controller is embedded inside a `UINavigationController"` and a `UITabBarController` and on it I have a custom segmented control which
is made from `UIView`s and `UIButton`s, and a `UITableView` with custom cells.
The second view controller consists of a `UIScrollView` and a `UIView` (like on the image above, just bigger a little). That `view` contains a `UIImageView`, `UILabel`s and a smaller `UIView` which is used as button to close the view by tapping on it.

Here is the code that I use to close the second view controller by dragging it down (`UIScrollViewDelegate`'s methods).

```
extension AuthorInfoViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isDragging = true
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard isDragging else {
        return
    }

    if !isDismissingAuthorInfo && scrollView.contentOffset.y < -30.0 && dismissAnimator != nil {
        authoInfoViewControllerDelegate?.authorInfoViewControllerWillDismiss()
        isDismissingAuthorInfo = true
        dismissAnimator?.wantsInteractiveStart = true
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    if isDismissingAuthorInfo {
        let progress = max(0.0, min(1.0, ((-scrollView.contentOffset.y) - 30) / 90.0))
        dismissAnimator?.update(progress)
    }
}

func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let progress = max(0.0, min(1.0, ((-scrollView.contentOffset.y) - 30) / 90.0))

    if progress > 0.5 {
        dismissAnimator?.finish()
    } else {
        dismissAnimator?.cancel()
        print("Canceled")
    }

    isDismissingAuthorInfo = false
    isDragging = false
}
}
```

Here, `isDismissingAuthorInfo` and `isDragging` are booleans which keep 
track whether the view is dismissing  and is dragged at all. `authorInfoViewControllerWillDismiss` is a method implemented in a protocol to which conforms the first view controller. That methods calls another method which adds the blur animation to the custom transitions animator.

**EDITED**

The animator code is the following:

```
class DismissAnimator: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning  {

var auxAnimationsForBlur: (()->Void)?
var auxAnimationsForTabBar: (()->Void)?
var auxAnimationsCancelForBlur: (()->Void)?
var auxAnimationsCancelForTabBar: (()->Void)?
var tabBar: UITabBar?
var blurView: UIView?


let transitionDuration = 0.75


func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {

    return transitionDuration
}

func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    transitionAnimator(using: transitionContext).startAnimation()
}

func transitionAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating {

    let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

    let container = transitionContext.containerView
    let from = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!

    container.addSubview(from)

    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, curve: .easeOut)

    animator.addAnimations({
        from.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: container.frame.size.height + 30)
    }, delayFactor: 0.15)

    animator.addCompletion { (position) in
        switch position {
        case .end:
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            self.tabBar?.isHidden = false 
            self.blurView?.removeFromSuperview()
        default:
            transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
            self.auxAnimationsCancelForBlur?()
            self.auxAnimationsCancelForTabBar?()
        }

    }

    if let auxAnimationsForBlur = auxAnimationsForBlur {
        animator.addAnimations(auxAnimationsForBlur)
    }

    if let auxAnimationsForTabBar = auxAnimationsForTabBar {
        animator.addAnimations(auxAnimationsForTabBar)
    }

    return animator

}

func interruptibleAnimator(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> UIViewImplicitlyAnimating {
    return transitionAnimator(using:transitionContext)
  } 
}
```

In the code above, the `auxAnimationsForBlur` is for adding blur animation to the animator, the `auxAnimationsCancelForBlur` is for canceling it, `auxAnimationsForTabBar` is for adding the animation of `alpha` value of `tabBar`, `auxAnimationsCancelForTabBar` is for canceling it.

Now, the problem is the following: the animation works fine, but after running it by dragging the second view controller for several times (5-9, approximately), after the transition is over and the first view controller is shown, it just stops responding. However, on the bottom I have a `tab bar`, and it works. So, when I change to another tab and return back, I see the second view controller and a black screen behind it (where the first view controller should have been). When this happens the `cancel` method on `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` gets called, from `scrollViewWillEndDragging` method above (on the console I see the word `cancel` printed). Is it possible that `cancel` method on `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` doesn't causes this problem, because when I comment out the call to that method, it seems everything works ok (in that case, I also comment out the call to `interruptibleAnimator(using:)` method on my animator, so I lose the interactive behaviour of the transition)? I couldn't reproduce this behaviour while closing the second view controller by tapping on a close button, so I think it has something to do with dragging.

What could cause this problem, and what could you suggest for solving it? I would appreciate all your help.

Comment: well, you yourse;f can guess that interactive transition implementation has some thing to do with it, so why don't you include it too? and while you're at it, you should include animator as well

Comment: @MilanNosáľ, I've already included the interactive transition. It is implemented in a `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods. I've edited my question, and added animator code, too.

Comment: there is some `dismissAnimator` property, about which we know nothing.. you also claim you implemented a demo app that uses the same implementaiton - why not share it?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ, `dismissAnimator` is the instance of the class `DismissAnimator` (I've added the implementation of the class in the edited version of the question). You want me to add the code of the demo app, too?

Comment: I guess if you can't replicate the issue with it it won't help.. but that means that you have two version, one working one buggy - I think you have better chances to determine the problem, especially if the working version uses the same code you showed us here

Comment: @MilanNosáľ, Yes, the code is almost identical, except that the buggy version also animates tab bar's `alpha` value and, as I mentioned in the question, `view controllers` are a little bit "heavier".